# DisposableEffect with lifeCycleOwner's LifeCycle.Event.ON_RESUME events are called in LOOP for some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack Compose version: 1.4.0-alpha02
Jetpack Compose component used: DisposableEffect & LocalLifecycleOwner
Android Studio Build:
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 RC 3
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9424903, built on December 20, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.2
Kotlin version:1.7.21

Device: samsung SM-N960U1, samsung SM-N950U
OS Version: 10, 9

Steps to Reproduce or Code Sample to Reproduce:

1. No specific steps and happening randomly at production Environment

## Code Samples:

The intention is to perform the refresh call whenever screen renders first time or onResume or comes from background to foreground at Dashboard page

Here is the reusable function to detect the ON_RESUME events

```
@Composable
fun AttachLifeCycleEvent(
    onCreateCallback: (() -> Unit)? = null, onResumeCallback: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    val lifeCycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    // If `lifecycleOwner` changes, dispose and reset the effect
    DisposableEffect(lifeCycleOwner) {
        val eventObserver = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                    Timber.d("ON_PAUSE")
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                    Timber.d("ON_REUME")
                    scope.launch {
                        onResumeCallback?.invoke()
                    }
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> {
                    Timber.d("OnCreate")
                    onCreateCallback?.invoke()
                }
                else -> {
                    Timber.d("Else branch of $event")
                }
            }
        }
        Timber.d("Add Observer")
        // Add the observer to the lifecycle
        lifeCycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(eventObserver)
        // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the observer
        onDispose {
            Timber.d("Removed Observer")
            lifeCycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(eventObserver)
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage at Dashboard screen:

```
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(
    dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel
) {
    AttachLifeCycleEvent(onResumeCallback = {
       // This block is calling multiple times in loop both foreground & background mode
        dashboardViewModel.refresh()
    })
}
```

## Observation:

In some devices and some edge cases , refresh call goes in LOOP and we couldn't reproduce this issue at DEV environment

The intention is to perform the refresh call whenever screen renders first time or onResume or comes from background to foreground at Dashboard page. But, in some devices (like OS 9,10) the call goes in LOOP due to DisposableEffect

Comment: Did you see the [example directly in the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect)? It uses `rememberUpdatedState` on each lambda, but your code doesn't.

Comment: True, we just added that and we need to see how it behave in PROD. BTW, here I was using `rememberCoroutineScope()` inside the DisposableEffect, may be this could have created the loop. I will update this thread asap it is fixed